# How to paginate R output?

Tags: r

I've been reading the R source code trying to understand how it paginates help pages (for example `?c`). I think it's using `less`, but I haven't been able to find the function that does this. I guess I could do `system(gettextf("echo %s | less", my_text))`, but it won't work in Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at `?page` and `?file.show`:

```
page(runif(1e5))
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's a way to page text without saving it to a file?

Comment: @nochocab: `page` use a temporary file, too. I don't know whether/how you could achieve pagination without a temporary file.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @sgibb, `page()` is really useful.  There are some cases where I want to go with a more complicated solution though.  You can also use [?sink](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sink.html) in conjunction with [?file.show](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/file.show.html):

```
sink(file="tempSink", type="output")
  ...
  # various commands
  ...
sink()
file.show(file="tempSink", delete.file=TRUE, title="my output")
```

For example, `page()` only displays one output, but you may want to look at several together.  I've also noted that sometimes `page()` doesn't work, but the above will (I don't know why--it might just be a bug).

Comment: It is exactly the same what `page` does if you use `method="print"` (have a look at: `page(page)`). Sure, you have to include your *various commands* into a function.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that with `page()` you need to specify `method="print"` to get the readable formatting you saw from the prompt:

```
> smry = summary(...)
> page(smry) # this is incomprehensible
structure(list(`Response Y1` = structure(list(call = lm(formula = Y1 ~ 
    designmatrix + 0), terms = Y1 ~ designmatrix + 0, residuals = new("VectorSpaceModel", 
    .Data = structure(c(0.0787047361879546, -1.45136789927732, 
...
> page(smry, method="print") # much better
Response Y1 :

Call:
lm(formula = Y1 ~ designmatrix + 0)

Residuals:
           [,1]
Min    -5.48880
...
```

If you don't want to wait for the whole darn thing to finish outputting before you get to look at the first line, try this:

```
> capture.output(smry, file=pipe("less"))
```

It produces the same result as `page(.., method="print")` for me, but the first line comes up immediately rather than after 4 seconds of silent buffering (for this particular example).

Also, sometimes after playing around with `capture.output` and friends you find that stuff you enter on the R prompt stops producing output, then you need to call `sink()` or [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948882/r-output-not-appearing-after-calling-sink).