# R output not appearing after calling sink()

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a collection of complicated R scripts, and decided to have all my debug-related messages called via `message()`. I was trying to find a way to suppress all messages, and stumbled upon this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767751/how-can-you-always-suppress-messages-in-r), which recommended I try using `sink()`. So I inserted the following lines of code into my script, and set my `config$debug_mode <- FALSE`:

```
if (!config$debug_mode){
  messages <- file("messages.Rout", open = "wt")
  sink(messages, type = "message")
}
```

The other SO post and R documentation says to simply call `sink()` or `sink(file=NULL)` to stop the previous diversion, but this is not working for me. Even after calling `sink()`, I don't see the R Studio console output from my `message()` calls. Also, `sink.number()` returns `0`, which seems to suggest that there are no diversions in place. Why, then, am I no longer seeing output in my R Studio console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you've initially indicated that you want to sink only messages, running `sink()` does not turn that behavior off. Instead, use `sink(type="message")`, which does what you're wanting.

```
> config <- list()
> config$debug_mode <- FALSE
> if (!config$debug_mode){
+   messages <- file("messages.Rout", open = "wt")
+   sink(messages, type = "message")
+ }
> message("trial")
> sink(type="message")
> message("trial")
trial
```

This is likely what is being (obliquely) referenced in the "Warning" section of the `?sink` help file, which includes this note:

> Do not sink the messages stream unless you understand the source code
>   implementing it and hence the pitfalls.

Comment: Appreciate that insight. However, calling `sink(type="message")` does not solve the issue. No messages are being displayed in my console.

Comment: @YuChen Hmm. I wonder if that's an RStudio issue, or if there's some other detail you haven't included here. The output I just added to my post was got by running the code in the basic R for Windows GUI...

Comment: @YuChen FWIW, I also get the same output on an (old) version of RStudio (v. 1.0.136).

Comment: Got it working. You were right from the beginning. I had a typo: `sink(type="messages")`.

Comment: @YuChen Great. Good catch.

Comment: `message("message not printed")` followed by `message("this message is printed")` would make the example more conclusive.

Comment: If this is part of a function which you are replicating then the `messages` connection that has been left open will cause a Error in file("messages.Rout", open = "wt") : all connections are in use error on the next function call. This is solved by adding `close(messages)` as a final line.